# How is the amino group basic?

Tags: acid-base, amino-acids

According to the Khan Academy, the amino functional group is basic because it can remove $\ce{H+}$ from systems. Why is that?

> [image: amine]
>
> Amino: Charged (forms $\ce{R-NH3+})$ at the pH of most biological systems. Since amino groups can remove $\ce{H+}$ from solution, they are considered basic.

My current understanding:

- The $\ce{H+}$ atoms bond in a polar covalent way with $\ce{N-}$. So that means the amino acid does not release that many $\ce{H+}$ ions. I can see why this is not acidic.
- $\ce{N-}$ also takes electrons from $\ce{R}$, which makes $\ce{R}$ become $\ce{R+}$. This should repel $\ce{H+}$ from elsewhere in solutions.

How does this functional group remove $\ce{H+}$ from its solutions?

Comment: R-NH2 + H+ -> [R-NH3]+

Comment: Right! Totally forgot that N requires 3 more electrons to be stable, not 2. Thanks! But what, then bonds the N to the R?

Comment: You have that on your own picture. Amin groups are bonded to R. There is equilibrium $\ce{R-NH2 + H2O <=> R-NH3+ + OH-}$ or $\ce{R-NH2 + H3O+ <=> R-NH3+ + H2O}$ It is the same as with ammonia.

Answer (score 2):

Polarity and elementary electrostatics have nothing to do with acid-base definitions. Sometimes we try to find a reason, using our current understanding, and that ensues the danger of over-rationalization. At a truly fundamental level perhaps no chemist can tell you why an amine can accept another proton, may be someone can do quantum mechanical calculations and say why. So avoid over-rationalization... accept some observations as facts (temporarily until we develop a full understanding).

One can titrate an amine with an acid, by this experimentally observed fact, exactly just like we titrate NaOH with HCl. So an amine group is indeed a base or say it behaves like base. The acidic proton cannot annihilate itself during a titration, it has to go somewhere. The amine group gets protonated, in return.

Comment: Is there *no* prior concept at all in chemistry that explains why this is basic? I have no idea why, for example, some atoms are stable with 2 shells of electrons, but taking that as a given, I can see why an oxygen atom wants 2 more. What is the given in this case?

Comment: Perhaps a theoretical chemist can tell you a fundamental reason. I am not one of them. My understanding is basically from an experimental perspective. Amines can be titrated with acids, and some amines can turn red litmus blue.

Answer (score 0):

1. According to Lewis acid-base concept, a molecule with central atom having lone pair can act as proton acceptor. In $\ce{R-NH2}$ there are lone pairs over $\ce{N}$ atom, which can combine with $\ce{H+}$ ions.
2. This can also be explained by Brønsted–Lowry concept, which states if an atom  accepts protons (like above), it is a base.

Comment: The latter came as an anhancement of the original Arrhenius model where acids release H+ and bases OH-.  But is does not apply to ammnia/amines, while the B-L model does.